# Text box date is not formted as expected

Tags: vba

i  have written a vba code that populates a text box value 
In vba code i have written some thing like this

```
dim  st_day as date
st_date  = format(date -7 , "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

and i have assinged this value to a `textbox` using `me.textbox1`  
But the text box displaying a value as 03/21/2014 but what i am expecting is the text box  
should display is  03/21/2014 00:00:00 AM  . 
can you kindly help me  where i am worng   ?

Comment: That should work - it would help to post your full code.

Answer (score 1):

Have u declared st_Date as date ..if so change the data type to variant ..

Something like this ..**Tested**

```
Sub tetetse()
Dim st_Date As Variant

st_Date = Format(Date - 7, "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

End Sub
```